# How to use TSec (with http4s) for per resource authorisation

Tags: scala, authorization, http4s

I'm currently setting up a new http4s server and looking into the authentication/authorisation mechanism and found TSec.

After going through [TSec's documentation](https://jmcardon.github.io/tsec/docs/http4s-auth.html) and also [this example code](https://github.com/jmcardon/tsec/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/http4sExamples/jwtStatefulWithRolesExample.scala), I couldn't figure out a way to implement authorisation on a per resource basis.

Say, for example, I can do the following to authorise an admin user (taken from example above):

```scala
TSecAuthService.withAuthorization(AdminRequired) {
  case request @ GET -> Root / "account" asAuthed user =>
    Ok()
}
```

But how do I authorise admin user of a particular account based on the path:

```scala
GET -> Root / "account" / AccountId(accid)
```

such that only admin user from the particular account (i.e., `accid`) is authorised?

I had a look into the few instances documented [here](https://jmcardon.github.io/tsec/docs/http4s/authorization.html) but they don't seem to fit my requirement.

Comment: Documentation contains an example of a service with authentication (not just authorization). You can use it. You'll have an access to `User` object and could manually reject the request if id of the resource doesn't match id of the user.

Comment: @andrewscs, did you find out how to use TSec authorization? Any link to a concrete example?